# Why main method is not convert into daemon thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, daemon, terminate

I am not clear with **daemon thread** in java,why main method cannot be convert into daemon thread and how can we know that daemon thread is terminated by jvm ?

Comment: Imagine if the main thread were a daemon thread; it would start up, there would immediately be no non-daemon threads so the process would be terminated. Doesn't sound very useful, does it? You can emulate the same behaviour with an empty `main()` method if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

**how can we know that daemon thread is terminated by jvm**

Wrong.
The JVM terminates when all threads running in it are *daemon threads*. Making main thread a daemon thread would do no good.

Typically, daemon threads are used to do clean-up tasks i.e, the tasks that can be stopped (unlike the *core / important part* of your app) without affecting the app too much.